# Adding a prefix in php

Tags: php

I'm setting up a phone system that will transfer a caller to a phone number in a database.  The numbers however need to have a prefix of "1" in order to be correctly dialed using voip.  Can anyone help?  This is what I have so far (worked great until voip changed their setting):

```
// Get the ID from PBX
$custid =   $_POST['id'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phone_list WHERE ani = '$custid'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
//Strips White Space
$transferani = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $row['phone']);
// Strips white space from beginning
echo ltrim($transferani);
}
// Close Connection
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `$transferani = '1'.$transferani;` Will this do the job o.O ?

Comment: It doesn't look like it works.  I tried but the call failed.  The numbers stored in the database are in all different formats, which is why I have to strip special characters.

Comment: Well you see this is one way to add a prefix, i just guessed the variable name. Could you provide exactly the output and the desired output ?

Comment: After all i guessed right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$prefix = '1';

$complete_number = $prefix.$transferani;
```

Or:

```
$complete_number = '1'.$transferani;
```

But if you don't want to change your variable name, use this:

```
$transferani = '1'.$transferani;
```

[String concatenation in PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php)